# Matlab Function with Varying parameters

Tags: matlab, function, debugging

I need help figuring out how to code the following problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Create a function that will take a vector/array input for `x` (`1 by n`) and a scalar input for `a`, and produce the output defined by the following equation:

```
y(x,a)=((xsin(ax-2))/(sqrt(1+(ax)^2)  
-π ≤ x ≤ π  
a={.5 1 1.5 2}
```

The equation must be vectorized in terms of `x` and the output from the function is the array `y` which has the same dimension as the array `x`.

Write a script that calls this function to compute `y(x,a)` for the range of `x` defined above and each value of the parameter `a`.  Results should be stored in a solution matrix using a different row of the solution matrix for each value of `a`.

So far for my function I have:

```
function [y] = part1(a,x)
y=((x*sin(a*x-2))/(sqrt(1+(a*x).^2)));
end
```

I'm not sure how to output this into the solution matrix

For my script I have:

```
%%
clear,clc

a={0.5 1 1.5 2};
x=-pi:0.1:pi;

for
    part1(x,a)
end
```

I'm getting the following errors when I run this now:

```
Undefined function 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in part1 (line 4)
    y=((x*sin(a*x-2))/(sqrt(1+(a*x).^2)));

Error in labtest2 (line 8)
    y(i,:)=part1(x,a(i));
```

**EDIT**

I've made some changes and am still getting some errors that I cannot resolve.

Here is my full code for function followed by full code for script:

Function

```
function [y] = part1(x,a)

nx=numel(x);
na=numel(a);

y=((x.*sin(a.*x-2))./(sqrt(1+(a.*x).^2)));
size(y)=[nx na]
end
```

Script

```
%%
clear,clc

a={0.5 1 1.5 2};
x=-pi:0.1:pi;

for i = 1:length(a)
  y(i,:)=part1(x,a(i));
end
```

Errors

```
Undefined function 'times' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in part1 (line 6)
    y=((x.*sin(a.*x-2))./(sqrt(1+(a.*x).^2)));

Error in labtest2 (line 8)
    y(i,:)=part1(x,a(i));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Note that you've written

```
function [y] = part1(a,x)
```

but you call it in your script as

```
part1(x,a)
```

so you should probably correct that.

A few things jump out at me:

- You never assign the output of `part1(x,a)` to anything. You're told that

> > Results should be stored in a solution matrix using a different row of the solution matrix for each value of a.
> >     
> >     What I take this to mean is that the 1st row corresponds to `part1()` evaluated for the 1st element of `a`. Since we're operating on `x` which is a vector, that row will have multiple columns. Your output is indeed a matrix. In your case, `length(-pi:0.1:pi) == 63`, therefore `size(y) == [4 63]`, where `y` is your output matrix.

- Your `for` loop is backwards. You're told to accept scalar `a` and vector `x`. Therefore, your script should be something like:

  ```
  a = 0.5:0.5:2;
  x = -pi:0.1:pi;
  for i = 1:length(a)
      y(i,:) = part1(x, a(i));
  end
  ```

Note the use of [`length`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html) and the [`:`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator. I want to iterate between 1 to `length(a)` (in this case, `length(a) == 4`) so that I can use the current `a(i)` value as an index into my output matrix, `y`. The `:` operator in `y(i,:)` signifies "The `i`th row and **all** columns of `y` will take the value output by `part1(x,a(i))`."

- Your function needs to be changed up for [element-by-element operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arithmeticoperators.html). Notice that, for instance, `x*sin(a*x-2)` works for scalar `x` but not vectors. This is because `x` is a vector and `sin(a*x-2)` is also a vector (since the `sin` call will operate element-by-element and `a` is a scalar). Trying to multiply two vectors together will result in errors since MATLAB will try to perform a *matrix* multiplication. Resolve this by replacing `*` with `.*`. This way it is unambiguous that you are going to multiply these two vectors element-by-element. You'll also need to change `/` to `./`.

---

On another note, thank you for attempting to do your homework before asking SO for help. We've been getting a huge influx of questions from students that have made no attempt to do their own work before dumping it on us, so it's refreshing that we regulars of the MATLAB tag get to actual help out instead of telling people to do their own work.

Comment: Ok I fixed up some errors in the code and made the changes you suggested but I still have two issues

1. How do I assign the output solution matrix for the first part?

2. my code currently looks like this:

    a={0.5 1 1.5 2};
    x=-pi:0.1:pi;

    for i = 1:length(a)
      y(i,:)=part1(x,a(i));
    end

I am getting an error here stating "Error in labtest2 (line 8)
    y(i,:)=part1(x,a(i));"

Comment: Guess I can't add code into the comments...

I'm updating the original question with new question/errors

Comment: I just checked your function - you need to use element-by-element multiplication. See my edit, coming right up.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help.  I know it probably seems like a stupid easy problem but I've been stumped for hours and I've literally looked everywhere for help.

Comment: I just added that you need to change `/` to `./`. No worries about the help! It's what SO is for. Everyone has to start learning somehow. We just ask that MATLAB students attempt their homework before coming to our community to ask for help. I'm glad you took the time to attempt the work first.

Comment: Made some more changes as you suggested.  Made an edit to original post with the errors.

Comment: @JohnRose not to be petty, but why did I lose the checkmark? Note that you can upvote other answers if they're helpful without saying that something is **THE** answer (ie awarding the checkmark). While the answer that's currently checkmarked is helpful, I don't think it answers your question as it was originally posed.

Comment: Yea I reverted it back.  Sorry I'm new on this site, It thought the check mark meant that it was a helpful/relevant post.  Your input ultimately led me to the correct coding and I really appreciate it.

Comment: Just hit the up-arrow above scores to denote that an answer was helpful! That's what it's there for :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting `Undefined function 'times' for input arguments of type 'cell'` is because your variable `a` is a cell array. You need to change your assignment of `a` from

```
a={0.5 1 1.5 2};
```

to

```
a=[0.5 1 1.5 2];
```

which will make it just a normal array. Alternatively, you need to reference it with cell array notation: `a{i}` instead of `a(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the whole thing worked out.

Function

```
function [y] = part1(x,a)

    y=((x.*sin(a.*x - 2))./(sqrt(1 + (a.*x).^2)));

end
```

Script

```
%%
clear all;
clc;
close all;

x=[-pi:.1:pi];
a=[.5:.5:2];

for i=1:length(a)
   y(i,:)=part1(x,a(i));

  plot(x,y)
end

Sol=[y]
```

Comment: You don't need to assign stuff with `[]` like you have for `x`, `a`, or `Sol`. `-pi:.1:pi` is already a vector, for instance. In fact, there are times when doing this is a *bad* thing. [Link to relevant MATLAB Answers discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35676-why-not-use-square-brackets)